# C# processing UTF8 Text File and Degree characters

Tags: c#, text, character-encoding

I'm processing a text file (VB6 Source file) using the following code

```
Encoding currentEncoding;
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(_sourceFile, true))
            {
                 currentEncoding = reader.CurrentEncoding;
            }
```

......

```
var fileasText = File.ReadAllLines(_sourceFile, currentEncoding);
```

I'm passing each line into a function, which performs (or rather in this case doesn't) some process, which in turn returns a string. I'm collecting all these strings and finally rewriting the text file using:

```
   File.WriteAllLines(Path.GetDirectoryName(_sourceFile) + @"\" + SourceFilename, newLines.ToArray(), currentEncoding);
```

This is working fine, but I'm losing some special characters, for example degree characters. I've tried various encodings when reading and writing the files, but the degree characters are still getting messed up. It's actual source code I'm rewriting so getting the file perfect is fairly essential.

I'm reading the current encoding of the text file (which returns UTF8) and using this to encode the saved file, so why should I be getting characters messed up? I'm not changing encoding methods.

Thanks for any help

p.s. Just to be clear, the lines which contain the corrupted characters are not being altered by the function. The function simply looks at it and returns false to signify that it does not require special handling. The line is then added to an array of strings and the next line processed.

Comment: You have to **set** the current encoding.  The `StreamReader` **defaults** to UTF8.  It literally has no way to know what the encoding of the file is and you must tell it.

Comment: Vb6 and utf8 have not ever been seen in the same room together.  Well, continent.  Use Encoding.Default

Comment: @Kevin. Thanks I thought reader.CurrentEncoding was a determination of the file's encoding.I'll try this.

Comment: Encodings can be a little tricky.  Many people don't even run into them until years into their carreer.

Comment: @Hans Passant. This worked, thanks. If you post this as an Answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @MuckersMate Encoding.Default is not recommended.  You really want to know and specify your encoding to make sure your code works consistently.  Encoding.Default changes from computer to computer and can be changed even on the same computer.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the encoding.  `StreamReader` defaults to UTF8 which evidently is not what your file actually is.

My guess is that your file is actually Unicode... though it could certainly be a different encoding.  It is critical to know what your encoding is when you have text files so you can guarantee to read them properly.

```
// Reading
var fileasText = File.ReadAllLines(_sourceFile, Encoding.Unicode);

// Writing
File.WriteAllLines(Path.GetDirectoryName(_sourceFile) + @"\" + SourceFilename, 
     newLines.ToArray(), Encoding.Unicode);
```